# Navigating back from second page to first php page not showing correct divs in first page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have first php page in which there are some checkboxes.I select the checkboxes and divs present in the page are filtered and when after filtering,I click a div and navigates to second php page.where i show the details of that product.But when i press back button from browser and navigate to first page.The problem which i m having here is when i navigate back to previous page,checkboxes which were checked they are checked only but divs are not filtered.

firstpage.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function get_check_value() {
            var c_value = [];

            $('input[name="brand"]:checked').each(function () {
                c_value.push(this.value);
            });
            return c_value.join(',');

        }
        function get_store_value(){
        var d_value=[];
            $('input[name="store"]:checked').each(function () {
                d_value.push(this.value);
            });
            return d_value.join(',');
            }

    $(document).ready(function(){
   checkboxValidate = function (e) {
   if(e)e.preventDefault();
    alert("hi");
        //var os = $('#originState').val();
       //var c = $('#commodity').val();
        //var ds = $('#destState').val();
        var ser = get_check_value();
        var store=get_store_value();
        //var queryString = "os=" + os;
        var data = "?ser=" + ser;
        var queryString = "&ser=" + ser;
        alert(ser);
       $.ajax({
       //alert("ajax");
        type: "POST",
        url: "sortingajax.php",
        data: {ser:ser,store:store},
        dataType :  'html',
        success: function (b) {
           // alert(a+' ok. '+b)
            $('#results').html(b);
            console.log(b);
        }
    });

    } 
    $( "[type=checkbox]" ).change(checkboxValidate);
    checkboxValidate
});
    </script>


    brand
        <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Sunbaby" id="check" />Sunbaby
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Advance Baby" id="check"/>Advance Baby
        <br/>
        store
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="store" value="Flipkart" id="check"/>Flipkart
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="store" value="Supermart" />Suoermart
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="store" value="Target" />Target
        <br/>


    <button id="btnSubmit">sort</button>
    <?php
    $secondsql ='SELECT * FROM xml WHERE  ('.implode ('AND',$parts).')limit '.$offset.', '.$limit1.'';
    //print($secondsql);
    $sql2=mysql_query($secondsql);
    $nameArray2=array();
    //echo "<br />";
    //echo $numrows;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
        // Append to the array


        $nameArray2[] = $row;



        //echo $row['PID']."<BR />";
    }

    foreach($nameArray2 as $array)
    {$i = 1;
    ?>
    <div>
    <a href="secondpage.php?name=<?php $array['IMAGEURL']?>">iMAGELINK</a></div>
    <?php
    }
    $i++;
    ?>

    <div id="results">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

sortingajax.php

```
 <?php

include('connection.php');
$query=$_POST['ser'];
$query1=$_POST['store'];
echo $query;
echo $query1;

$query=explode(",",$query);
$query = array_filter($query);
$query1=explode(",",$query1);
$query1 = array_filter($query1);
$result=count($query);
$result1=count($query1);
//echo $result;
echo $result1;
$parts = array();
$limit = 10;
    $offset = 0;
if(!empty($query))
{
foreach( $query as $queryword ){
    $parts[] = '`BRAND` LIKE "%'.$queryword.'%"';

}
$brandsql='SELECT * FROM XML WHERE  ('.implode ('OR',$parts).')  order by price asc';
    $brandsql1=mysql_query($brandsql);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($brandsql1);  
$countArray=array();
print($brandsql);
echo "<br />";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($brandsql1)) {
    // Append to the array


    $countArray[] = $row;



    //echo $row['PID']."<BR />";
}
}
$parts1=array();
if(!empty($query1)){
foreach( $query1 as $queryword1 ){
    $parts1[] = '`STORE` LIKE "%'.$queryword1.'%"';

}
$storesql='SELECT * FROM XML WHERE  ('.implode ('OR',$parts1).') order by price desc';
    $storesql1=mysql_query($storesql);
$numrows1 = mysql_num_rows($storesql1); 
$countArray=array();
print($storesql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($storesql1)) {
    // Append to the array


    $countArray[] = $row;



    //echo $row['PID']."<BR />";
}
}
?>


<?php
foreach($countArray as $array)
{



?>

<div>
<a href="secondpage.php?name=<?php $array['IMAGEURL']?>">iMAGELINK</a></div>

<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Secondphp page

```
<?php
$IMAGE=$_GET['name'];
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="<?php echo $IMAGE?>"/>
</body>
</html>
```

In the first page when i check any checkbox,with ajax call imageslink present in the page are filtered.and then i click on any link and pass it to second php page.there image is displayed.But when i press back button,and go to first page.it shpws checkboxes checked,but divs are not filtered..
Please help me on this..and comment if more info is required.

Comment: This is because you are filtering using javascript onclick or onchange... You need to run the same script after DOM ready too...

Comment: @Salketer-I didnt get man..Can u please elaborate on what do i need to change?

Comment: Where do i need to chnage the script ...

Answer (score 0):

Replace your ready function by this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   checkboxValidate = function (e) {
   if(e)e.preventDefault();
    alert("hi");
        //var os = $('#originState').val();
       //var c = $('#commodity').val();
        //var ds = $('#destState').val();
        var ser = get_check_value();
        var store=get_store_value();
        //var queryString = "os=" + os;
        var data = "?ser=" + ser;
        var queryString = "&ser=" + ser;
        alert(ser);
       $.ajax({
       //alert("ajax");
        type: "POST",
        url: "sortingajax.php",
        data: {ser:ser,store:store},
        dataType :  'html',
        success: function (b) {
           // alert(a+' ok. '+b)
            $('#results').html(b);
            console.log(b);
        }
    });

    } 
    $( "[type=checkbox]" ).change(checkboxValidate);
    checkboxValidate();
});
```

Note that the trick here is to filter when the checkboxes value are changed. But when you open the page and the checkboxes are already checked, you need to run the same script again to filter.

Comment: I edited the code as u have shown buddy,but still when i navigate back from to first page from second page.records are not filtered according to checkbox selected on start.i have updated my code according to ur change..please check sir where its wrong....

Comment: I am very sorry, I made a mistake, this should fix it.